Is there a way to overlay a Tomorrow.io weather map onto a Kepler.gl map?
I'm trying to figure out how to overlay a weather map generated by Tomorrow.io onto a Kepler.gl map in my React app.
I know that to add a data layer in Kepler.gl, the data must be geospatial. However, unless I'm mistaken, I'm finding that Tomorrow.io can only generate static PNG weather maps based on a location's coordinates and a zoom value.
I expect the user to:

Click on a map and extract the coordinates (or input an address, whose coordinates are determined using Google Maps API),
Make a GET request to Tomorrow.io,
Receive the raw PNG data and create a PNG file, and
Overlay the PNG onto the base map, centered at the specified coordinates.

Ideally, I want a simple 2D solution similar to what was implemented in this thesis. So far, I have found no way to do so.
I am wondering:

Is there a way to overlay a PNG image onto a Kepler.gl map?
Are there alternatives to Tomorrow.io that generate GeoJSON weather maps which can be layered onto a Kepler.gl map?
Am I on the right track?

For reference, here is my app reducer in store.ts:
const appReducer = handleActions(
  {
    [ActionTypes.LAYER_CLICK]: (state, action: LayerClickAction) => {
      const { coordinate } = action.payload.info;
      const [longitude, latitude] = coordinate;
      const { zoom } = action.payload.info.viewport;
      fetchWeatherMap({ latitude, longitude, zoom }).then(
        (pngData) => {
          if (!pngData) {
            console.error("No data found.");
            return;
          }

          // TODO: Render PNG centered at the clicked coordinate
        }
      );
      return state;
    },
  },
  initialAppState
);

Here is my map-fetching utility function:
export const fetchWeatherMap = async ({
  latitude,
  longitude,
  zoom,
  dataField = "precipitationIntensity",
}: {
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;
  zoom: number;
  dataField?: string;
}) => {
  const TIMESTAMP = new Date().toISOString();
  const url = `https://api.tomorrow.io/v4/map/tile/${zoom}/${longitude}/${latitude}/${dataField}/${TIMESTAMP}.png?apikey=${process.env.REACT_APP_TOMORROW_API_KEY}`;
  const { data } = await axios.get(url);
  return data;
};

Any feedback and suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.
